# How to make the bar chart starts from the bottom to top in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, bar-chart

I would like to make the bar chart starts from bottom to top in flutter because my bar chart is starting from top to down and this is leaving a bad impact for the users. So, how to can I make the bar chart starts from the bottom to top in flutter?

Bellow are two widgets of the bar chart, I just spread them into two different files.

```
     print('build() ChartBar');
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (ctx, constraints) {
      return 
      Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.15,
            child: FittedBox(
              child: Text('\$${spendingAmount.toStringAsFixed(0)}'),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.05,
          ),
          Container(
            height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.6,
            width: 10,
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey, width: 1.0),
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(220, 220, 220, 1),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                  ),
                ),
                FractionallySizedBox(
                    heightFactor: spendingPercentageOfTotal,
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.purple,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                      ),
                    )),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.05,
          ),
          Container(
            height: constraints.maxHeight * 0.15,
            child: FittedBox(
              child: Text(label),
            ),
          )
        ],
      );
    });
  }
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build() Chart');
    return Card(
      elevation: 6,
      margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: groupedTransactionValues.map(
            (data) {
              return Flexible(
                  fit: FlexFit.tight,
                  child: ChartBar(
                      data['day'],
                      data['amount'],
                      totaLSpending == 0.0
                          ? 0.0
                          : (data['amount'] as double) / totaLSpending));
            },
          ).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this code below. Flutter default is from top to bottom. You can change this by using Align widget.

```
Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: FractionallySizedBox(....),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

add this into Stack widget

```
alignment: AlignmentDirectional.bottomStart,
```

Answer (score 0):

the easy way is to use dependencies

https://pub.dev/packages/fl_chart